# ftp alter server response in transit

Tags: ssl, proxy, ftp, ibm-midrange

I have a unique situation where one of my business partners runs a FTP server that is out of date and the client I need to use is slightly incompatible.

The server I'm connecting to returns a 334 response during connection and this causes the connection to be dropped by my ftp client.  The RFC changed since that server was released, the server should respond with a 234 instead of a 334.  I've talked with the client vendor (IBM) and they have indicated that they are not going to ignore the response or treat a 334 as a 234.  I have also talked to the business partner and they have no interest in upgrading or changing their server.

So i was thinking why not detect the 334 at say the packet level and replace the 334 with a 234? That would solve my problem (assuming there are no other protocol violations).

How would I go about this?  Running a proxy server? Anyone have any experience with this?

Any other options?

I have no choice but to use the client I am already running that is set in stone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem.
You might try to use iptables together with netsed as described at https://serverfault.com/a/321671/208324.

Apart from that IBM is right. It must be 234 as response to `AUTH TLS` and not 334, see [RFC4217 Sect. 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4217#section-4.2). The servers which still do it wrong are probably way too old anyway and still use SSL 3.0 only, so this is another issue you have to worry about and maybe it helps to put some pressure on your partner to replace the server.